# CodeIgniter: Insert a row into MySQL with timestamp

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In CodeIgniter, I want to insert a row into a db that includes a timestamp for "now".

```
$message_row = array(
            "sender_email" => $recruiter_email,
            "recipient_email" => $recruiter_email,
            "message" => $recruiter_email,
            "send_date" => "NOW()" // hmmm how do I do this?
        );

$this->db->insert('messages', $message_row);
```

If I use `"NOW()"` it will just enter the string, and not actual have MySQL use its `NOW` keyword.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/136688/#673742

Answer (score 1):

In order to use NOW() function in CodeIgniter you need to use "set" function

```
$table = 'user';    

$message_row = array(
        "sender_email" => $recruiter_email,
        "recipient_email" => $recruiter_email,
        "message" => $recruiter_email
    );

$this->db->set('send_date', 'NOW()', false);

$this->db->insert($table, $message_row);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to be timezone aware, i recommend you store the datetime in UTC format.
so:

```
   $now = new DateTime ( NULL, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
   $message_row = array(
        "sender_email" => $recruiter_email,
        "recipient_email" => $recruiter_email,
        "message" => $recruiter_email,
        "send_date" => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
```

when you retrieve the information, you have to know the user's timezone, using a $row that contains the send_date:

```
$then = new DateTime( $row->send_date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$then->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($userstimezone));
echo $then->format('Y-M-D H:i:s');
```